# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails on real server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a problem with the database on my web server but it's working on the local host.

This is my database design:
[image]

and this is the code of these three tables :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zeko2006_salesSystem`.`users` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`admin` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 0,
`name` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
`mail` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
`phone` DECIMAL(20) NULL,
`username` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC),
UNIQUE INDEX `mail_UNIQUE` (`mail` ASC),
UNIQUE INDEX `user_id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB

COMMENT = '<double-click to overwrite multiple objects>';
```

and this is the company code :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zeko2006_salesSystem`.`company` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`cp_source` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
`call_date` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
`cp_mail` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
`cp_mail_2` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
`cp_phone` DECIMAL(20) NULL,
`cp_phone_2` DECIMAL(20) NULL,
`cp_address` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
`cp_website` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
`cp_category` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
`user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `user_id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `cp_id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC),
UNIQUE INDEX `cp_name_UNIQUE` (`cp_name` ASC),
UNIQUE INDEX `cp_phone_UNIQUE` (`cp_phone` ASC),
UNIQUE INDEX `cp_website_UNIQUE` (`cp_website` ASC),
INDEX `fk_user_id_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_user_id`
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
REFERENCES `zeko2006_salesSystem`.`users` (`id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
COMMENT = '<double-click to overwrite multiple objects>';
```

and this is the company representative code :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zeko2006_salesSystem`.`company_rep` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`cp_rep_name` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
`cp_rep_position` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
`cp_rep_phone` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
`cp_rep_mail` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
`company_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `company_id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC),
UNIQUE INDEX `company_id_UNIQUE` (`company_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_cpmpany_id`
FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`)
REFERENCES `zeko2006_salesSystem`.`company` (`id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = '<double-click to overwrite multiple objects>';
```

When I insert a new user then insert a company:

```
INSERT INTO zeko2006_salesSystem.company (
    id, cp_source, call_date, cp_name, cp_mail, cp_mail_2,
    cp_phone, cp_phone_2, cp_address, cp_website, cp_category, user_id
) VALUES ('2', 'Friends', '25-4-2001', 'Media Club Egypt',
    'mc@gmail.com', 'mc@gmail.com', '01117962758',
    '01117962758', 'Egypt', 'www.sjdbfj.com', 'Media', '1'
);
```

This works fine but when I insert a company representative to this company it gives me this error :

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails    (`zeko2006_salesSystem`.`company_rep`, CONSTRAINT `fk_cpmpany_id` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `company` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see the insert statement that is failing in live? It seems that when you insert a `company_rep`, you are not adding in a valid `company` row. Incidentally, `fk_cpmpany_id` looks like it should be named `fk_company_id`.

Comment: I insert it via phpMyadmin .. i mean i insert it manually. The insert statment like : INSERT INTO `zeko2006_salesSystem`.`company` (`id`, `cp_source`, `call_date`, `cp_name`, `cp_mail`, `cp_mail_2`, `cp_phone`, `cp_phone_2`, `cp_address`, `cp_website`, `cp_category`, `user_id`) VALUES ('2', 'Friends', '25-4-2001', 'Media Club Egypt', 'mc@gmail.com', 'mc@gmail.com', '01117962758', '01117962758', 'Egypt', 'www.sjdbfj.com', 'Media', '1'); in company

Comment: When you insert in company_rep you probably dont have the company id in the company table.

Comment: no i have the company inserted correctly in company table

Comment: @halfer and this is the insert statement in company_rep table http://www.mediafire.com/download/vo4krbznon5a1ej/Comp.zip

Comment: Where is cp_name in company,you have an index on it?

Comment: i thinki i didn't get what you mean. But Media Club is the cp_name and this link mediafire.com/download/vo4krbznon5a1ej/Comp.zip may help us

Comment: @Mihai .. i do it manually using phpMyAdmin like this photo https://www.mediafire.com/?ptgqska3ssotc05

Comment: You still haven't shown us the INSERT (into `company_rep`) that fails.

Comment: @ypercube this photo show you http://www.mediafire.com/download/ptgqska3ssotc05/rep.PNG ... i insert via phpMyAdmin

Comment: I've added your `company` insert into your question. Please add your `company_rep` query in yourself - most readers here will not download files from file locker websites, especially if they also have to decompress them.

Answer (score 0):

In your `company` table you have:

```
UNIQUE INDEX `cp_name_UNIQUE` (`cp_name` ASC),
```

this index referencing a nonexistent column.

Otherwise,with the column added, it all works for me.

[**SQL fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d028e/1)

Comment: ok i forgot to write the the cp_name column in my code in the question

Comment: This code is working perfect on the local host but fail on server .. that's the problem .. can you try it on your own server ?\

Comment: Check if the db,table and columns are the same on your server.

Comment: I copied and pasted the same code in the local host and the server .. it works fine in local host but same error in the server !!!